# A FEW figures (literally)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**Which option corresponds best to the missing figure? Explain why.**

---

[image]

Comment: Is this also intended to be an entry to the current MTC? :0

Comment: @oAlt I got inspired :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> **C**

Because:

> in chemistry, this would represent **WATER** in [CPK colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPK_coloring) - two white hydrogen atoms and a red oxygen atom.

...which makes sense since the other 3 images are:

> dot-to-dots for the traditional [classical elemental symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element) for **air, fire and earth**, and the missing element here is *water* (which is usually represented as a downwards-pointing triangle, also alluded to in the arrangement of the three circles here).
>
>  [image: Symbols explained]

As for the title:

> 'A FEW' here stands for 'Air, Fire, Earth, and Water' and we are drawing *figures* depicting them (moreover, *in this particular order*).

Comment: Correct! Well done.